# PL/SQL Create trigger that checks if there's record in table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm creating database of car rental/carsharing.
I want create trigger that checks if there's active rental, by checking if end of rental IS NOT NULL and if it is null, then if it is not null, if it has the same car id.
I have no more ideas how to create that trigger... Thanks for any advice.

```
create or replace TRIGGER act_rental_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON "RENTALS" 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
end_of_rental date;
BEGIN  
   IF inserting THEN 
    IF end_of_rental IS NOT NULL THEN 
   IF (EXISTS ( 
      SELECT * FROM rentals 
      where rentals.car_id = :NEW.car_id ))
         THEN 
         dbms_output.put_line('You can't!'); 
    END IF; 
    END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-trigger/

Comment: What if `end_of_rental IS NULL`? Will the same car_id value be inserted into the table unlimited times in this case ?

Comment: [OP here] Nope, if it IS NULL, then this car cannot be rented right? I mean, if it IS NULL that means, that this car is rented, so my trigger won't let insert another rental.

Answer (score 0):

Why trigger? Why don't you do it in the application, once someone wants to rent a car?

Trigger should `raise_application_error`. Don't use `dbms_output.put_line` because no front-end application (I used) is capable of displaying its contents to the user (and I presume that you won't manipulate data in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer directly, but e.g. Apex or Forms application).

Moreover, the way you'd want to do it leads to *mutating table* error - you're inserting into *rentals* table and select from it (in the trigger); that's not allowed because table is *mutating*. Yes, there are ways to avoid it, but most often you see that error you have to ask yourself whether you're doing it *right*. In my opinion, you're trying to do it *wrong*.

---

By the way, what did you mean to say by this:

> ... by checking if end of rental IS NOT NULL and if it is null, then if it is not null

Huh?

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Well, my project is developed mainly for manipulating data in SQL Developer. Haha. But I wanted use it also in Apex, so thank you for pointing that thing. 
Ok, so how would you do it? I'm too newbie into pl/sql I just want to create trigger that won't let me insert new rental data once car is rented. 
I have no idea what I meant there. 
Just 2 conditions I wanted there. 
1st, if the end of rental IS NULL, if it is NOT NULL, then 
2nd, if the car_id is the same as :NEW.car_id. 
How would you solve this?

Comment: The procedure that creates the rental in the first place should be where you check if the car is already rented.  This is a poor use of triggers.

Comment: As you do use Apex, create a **validation**. Put all code you find necessary to check whether that particular car was rented and display a message if the car is not available.

Comment: yeah ok, I will create FUNCTION, but how to check when "if exists" is not allowed?

Comment: You'll SELECT INTO a locally declared variable. If SELECT returns a value, then "it exists". If SELECT raises NO_DATA_FOUND, you'll handle it.

Comment: Ok, I created function that checks for existing rental. Then I created procedure that performs INSERT when SELECT FUNCTION returns that car can be rented. Thank you guys for helping me. :)